# Converting from Unix Time giving the wrong result

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert a Unix time string to a Date in Xcode but I keeps getting the wrong time by two hours. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me please?

```
NSString *unixTime = @"1402473600";
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [unixTime doubleValue];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];
```

It gives me: 2014-06-11 10:00:00 CEST

... but it should be: 2014-06-11 08:00:00 CEST

Comment: It's "Wed, 11 Jun 2014 08:00:00 GMT" according to http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: Yes, but that's not what xcode is giving me...

Comment: xCode logs +0000 time while you want CEST time which has 2 hour difference.

Comment: Confirmed- when converting into your time zone, the correct date for Unix 1402473600 is `Jun 11 2014 10:00:00 GMT+2` which is CEST. Xcode is giving you exactly the correct value.

Comment: It's because you are using `[NSDate description]` in that `NSLog()` call.  Print the date using an `NSDateFormatter`, with the correctly configured time zone, and things will be different.

Comment: @turingtested Accept Keenie's answer as he is showing you how to do it with a proper answer.

Comment: Good point @trojanfoe! This might not be the smartest question on StackOverflow, still dates and timezones can be very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xCode returns you correct value that is in UTC+0 time zone. Do not forget that CEST is UTC+2. Here is code snippet to test it:

```
// your code
NSString *unixTime = @"1402473600";
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [unixTime doubleValue];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];
NSLog(@"%@", date); // 08:00:00 +0000

// CEST, UTC+2 formatting
NSDateFormatter *localDF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[localDF setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CEST"]]; // which is CEST, which is UTC+2
[localDF setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSLog(@"%@", [localDF stringFromDate:date]); // 10:00:00 +0200
```

You can convert your date to CEST timezone. Depending on result you can convert given date to a new date variable with adjusted value or create string representation based on required time zone:

**Variant 1. Return string representation of given date with timezone:**

```
NSDateFormatter *cestDF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[cestDF setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CEST"]]; // which is CEST, which is UTC+2
[cestDF setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSString *cestDateStr = [cestDF stringFromDate:date];
```

**Variant 2. New and adjusted date object:**

```
NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CEST"] secondsFromGMT];
NSTimeInterval cestTimeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + timeZoneOffset;
NSDate *cestDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:cestTimeInterval];
```

NOTE: `NSDate` has no concept of timezone inside it, so you should remember in which timezone is your `NSDate` variable.

Comment: Your conversion makes it 2 hours more wrong. I changed "+ timeZoneOffset" to "- timeZoneOffset".
Then it became right.

Comment: If you subtract you'll get 6:00. Do you receive unixTime in UTC+0?

Comment: You should be converting date either with NSDateFormatter or by manually adjusting given date using NSTimeZone. If you do both variant consequently, you'll get adjustment applied two times.

Comment: I'm really baffled. Isn't the Unix time the same everywhere on earth? I'm getting the unixTime from a server on the internet. Using variant 1, I get the right result by replacing @"CEST" with @"UTC"

Comment: Here is the gist that I tested on the device: https://gist.github.com/keenle/ba773a9fa330dd05ab5e. Try to run it please, do you observe the same results?

Comment: Okay, I got the same result. It seems that my first code above is correct ... but methods on NSDate and NSDateFormatter is making the time local for some reason. As I wrote, by writing [cestDF setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]]; instead, it stops doing that.